# How to create a three dimensional matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to create three dimensional matrix? For example:

A = matrix 4 * 5 (4 rows, 5 columns)

B = matrix 4 * 10 (4 rows, 10 columns)

How to turn these two matrices a three-dimensional matrix?

Comment: This should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com); I won't migrate since it is answered and you are new here, but please ask such future questions in a proper place.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation on [multidimensional arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86528.html).

Comment: yes, I did go through that before,, but the dimension of my matrix are different,, I read sth about HOSVD, whats that?

Comment: If your matrices are different dimensions, how exactly do you want to combine them?  You may need a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html).

Comment: sorry, i did not understand,,,,

Comment: You say you want to create a three dimensional matrix from A and B.  A and B both have 4 rows, however A has 5 columns and B has 10 columns.  So how did you want to 'line-up' A and B on the first two dimensions.  It may be easier if you explain why you want to combine A and B.

Comment: ok, let me put it this way, as part of my work, i need to create visual-texture document matrix as follow:

Comment: I have bag of words which it is a vector, every row represent the image and every column is the occurance 
of visual words, so my vector is 10 * 100, ( 10 image and 100 visual words). then my textual words also 
show the occurance of the keywords in the image, so this is a vector also, the rows represent images and 
column are the occurance of keywords, so for example i will have 10 * 50 vector, so the number of images 
are same in both vector,

Comment: so I want to have 3D vector, row represent 10 images, columns represent visual 
words which is 100 and another dimension like cube to represent textual keywords which is 50...

Comment: Based on that, I believe a [multidimensional cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86528.html#f1-87418) is what you want.  Cells in a cell array can be of any type (they don't have to be consistent among each other), and the multidimensional aspect will allow you to extend the array beyond 2D.